# What is the difference between the tickets in the 3 different locations within GetReservationRS

Tags: sabre

These sections sometimes have the same numbers, although AccountingLines often has the 10-digit version without airline code.

RESERVATION / PASSENGER_RESERVATION / PASSENGER / TICKETINGINFO

RESERVATION / PASSENGER_RESERVATION / ACCOUNTINGLINES

RESERVATION / PASSENGER_RESERVATION / TICKETINGINFO